# Sql Query To Return Notification from store table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012-express

I have a `store` table which have `productName`, `productNumber`, `storedInBranch`, `blockNumber`, `quantity`, `notifyIn`.

If the `quantity` is less than `notifyIn` it will notify me and I tried the query below:

```
select * from store
where (quantity < notifyIn) AND (notify > 0)
```

which works perfect but since one product can be stored in multiple `blockNumbers` it is notifying me even if the amount of products are not less than `notifyin`,

eg.:

```
productName = monitor, productNumber=123, storedInBranch=kenya, blocknumber=5b, quantity=5, notifyin=4

productName = monitor, productNumber=123, storedInBranch=kenya, blocknumber=<b>1a</b>, quantity=5, notifyin=4
```

so the above query returns both as low what I wanted to do is sum both `quantity` (5+5) and `notifyIn` 4.

Comment: Consider normalising your database schema further to remove repeating field. Can you extract products to their own table

Comment: Also extract branches to a table with the relevant branch info like notify limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying here on notifyin being the same value in multiple rows. You could do something like

```
SELECT productNumber, sum(quantity), min(notifyin)
FROM store
GROUP BY productNumber
HAVING sum(quantity) < min(notifyin)
```

I would encourage you to change your schema if possible to better reflect your domain logic. Maybe have a separate table with product number and notify in value. That way you are not duplicating the `notifyin` and risk storing different value in different rows.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps. Please accept my answer if it helped you to answer your question.